# The puppeteer in docker throws timeout error

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, next.js, puppeteer

I honestly has this as my only option. I simply want to create a pdf of my nextjs booking page. so, when user clicks on download brochure, I take their email, and send the pdf of that page to them as link to download.
I pre-generated this pdf when the seller publish or update their trip which others can book from.
I have checked another pdf library like PDF lib, the amount of work needed to design the page is not funny and I can't really find how to setup the page as I want. Stuff like flex and alignment, I just couldn't find how to use them! So, I returned to puppeteer which seems easy in terms of design!I setup the pdf design using regular css and it came out as I wanted. It worked locally too.
However, for three days now, I can't seem to be able to deploy puppeteer on docker.

Puppeteer does nothing than to print the pdf and send back the response to my main api. So, the docker simply is housing pupeteer, separate from my main api that controls the entire app. It wont be used on another site.
Here are my code:

I tried PDF lib but has strong learning curve to get the pdf designed well. And since I'm dealing with dynamic data with lots of images that could be png, jpeg, jpg, etc, PDF lib wasn't that robust for me and I don't have time for such implementation when it is not the core of the entire application.

Here is my puppeteer code:

```
export const httpCreatePDF = async(req: Request, res:Response)=>{



const url = req.body.url;
const prevPublicURL = req.body.prevPublicURL;
const tripId = req.body.tripId;


res.sendStatus(200);
try {

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true,
executablePath: 'google-chrome-stable',
args: ['--no-sandbox', ],

            
});

const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto(url,  {waitUntil: 'networkidle0',});
 page.setDefaultTimeout(5000)

const pdf = await page.pdf(
    { format: 'A4', });

await browser.close();

//delete prev pdf if it exist in cloudinary

if(prevPublicURL){
    await deleteAllFiles({filesToDelete: [prevPublicURL]});
};

//upload the file to cloudinary
const uploadResponse =  await cloudinaryBufferUpload(pdf) as any;

const response = {
    pdfImageURL: uploadResponse?.secure_url,
    pdfPublicURL: uploadResponse?.public_id,
    tripId: tripId
}


const webHookReq = await axios.post(sanitizedConfig.WEBHOOK_URL_PDF, response);

    if(webHookReq?.status === 200){

        return res.sendStatus(200);
    }
    /*else{

       await axios.post(sanitizedConfig.WEBHOOK_URL_PDF, response); 
    }*/ 
    return res.sendStatus(200)
 } catch (error) {

throw error
}
}
```

Docker file:

```
FROM node:slim

WORKDIR /app


#copy configs to /app folder
COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./


#copy source code to /app/src folder
COPY src /app/src

RUN npm install axios bcrypt cloudinary cookie-parser cors dotenv     express jsonwebtoken mongoose puppeteer

RUN npm install typescript --save-dev
RUN npm run build


FROM node:slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
&& wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
&& sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
  --no-install-recommends \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


WORKDIR /app



COPY package*.json ./ 

RUN npm install axios bcrypt cloudinary cookie-parser cors dotenv   express jsonwebtoken mongoose puppeteer

COPY --from=0 /app/build ./build


RUN npm uninstall typescript


USER node

CMD [ "npm", "start"]


EXPOSE 6000
```

Docker compose

```
version: "3"
services:

  pdfapi:
   build: .
   image: kings19/pdf-api
   ports:
    - "6000:6000"
   env_file:
    - /src/services/Env/.env
```

I deployed the app on Back4app host.
Here is the error each time the request to create a pdf occurs:

```
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process /task_queues:95:5)

at fulfilled (/app/build/src/controllers/pdf.js:5:58)

at Generator.next (<anonymous>)

 at /app/build/src/controllers/pdf.js:31:20

  at CdpPage.goto (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/api/Page.js:724:43)

  at CdpFrame.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/util/decorators.js:108:27)

  at CdpFrame.goto (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Frame.js:140:29)

  at new LifecycleWatcher (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/LifecycleWatcher.js:75:60)

at Deferred.create (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/util/Deferred.js:68:16)

at new Deferred (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/util/Deferred.js:26:34)

 TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded

 this.#timeoutError = new Errors_js_1.TimeoutError(opts.message);

 /app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/util/Deferred.js:26
```

I will appreciate any help to fix this. Thanks

UPDATE
I noticed that when I checked [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), it actually converted the page to a pdf. However, it is not converting my nextjs app page.
It is also important to note that it converted the same page to pdf on localhost.
It keeps timing out when trying to access that same page on deployment.
How can I fix this?
This is the page it is trying to access:

```
https://bookingapp-mocha.vercel.app/builder/live/64e3aaba042c8f73316d13f1-Experience-the-Cairo-vibes-at-Night
```

The page is server side rendered in nextjs and host on Render.com but on a free account for now. We are still test building.

Comment: "It worked locally too. However, for three days now, I can't seem to be able to deploy puppeteer on docker." Is it still working locally?

Comment: It worked locally as at when last I   tested. But that was about 3 weeks ago as I paused the implementation until the client deploys to paid Varcel host.